# Finding an item in std::vector

Tags: c++, vector, std

I want to check whether an element exists in the vector or not, so I can deal with each case.
I came across this formula :

```
#include <algorithm>

if ( std::find(vector.begin(), vector.end(), item) != vector.end() )
   do_this();
else
   do that();
```

I dont understand why do we need vector.end() at the end, isnt find(vector.begin(), vector.end(), item) enough to find the element ?

Comment: You might need to read a reference, like e.g. [this one](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find). You especially needs to read what `std::find` returns in case the thing you search for is not found.

Answer (score 3):

```
std::find(vector.begin(), vector.end(), item)
```

will return an Iterator, so by comparing it to

```
vector.end()
```

you are actually checking to see if such an iterator with that item exists.

Answer (score 1):

> I dont understand why do we need vector.end() at the end, isnt
>   find(vector.begin(), vector.end(), item) enough to find the element ?

The result of `find` on failing to find a match is an iterator pointing to the end of the range provided, and there's nothing particularly special about end iterators that allow them to be compared like a boolean state.

`find` was designed to be a general-purpose algorithm that works on a wide variety of containers (including even those potentially outside the standard library). It's also designed to do simply more than return whether an element was found or not -- it returns an iterator pointing to the item if found. As a result, it doesn't return null or anything like that if it fails to find the element. It returns iterators.

If you really do this kind of thing a lot (and I only recommend doing anything like this if you do, since you're introducing something foreign to daily code), you can do something like this:

```
/// @return True if `val` is found in `[first, last)`
template <class Iterator, class Element>
bool contains(Iterator first, Iterator last, const Element& val)
{
    return std::find(first, last, val) != last;
}

...
if (contains(vector.begin(), vector.end(), item))
   do_this();
else
   do_that();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's checking whether the value was actually found or not.
**std::find()** returns an iterator to the first element in the query range.
If the returned value is equal to **vector.end()** that means it didn't find the item.
See [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/) for more information.